# Is it true that $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}$, ($n>1$), where $\{a_n\}$ does not have a finite limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, inequality

Is it true that for a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset\mathbb{C}$ that does not converge to a finite limit $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}$, ($n>1$)?

It can be easily shown that   $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}\leq \limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$, but I have problem with proving the opposite inequality (or finding a counterexample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}=r$. Take $\epsilon>0$. Now for sufficiently large $m$ we have $|a_m-a_{m-1}|<(r+\epsilon)^m$, i.e. , there exists a constant $C$ such that $|a_n-a_{n-1}|<C(r+\epsilon)^n$ for all $n$. Consequently,
$$\begin{align}
|a_n| & \leq |a_1|+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |a_{k+1}-a_k|\\
& \leq C'(r+\epsilon)^n
\end{align}$$
Hence $\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq r+\epsilon$. Since the inequality for any $\epsilon>0$, we see $\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq r=\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that
$|a_1|+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |a_{k+1}-a_k|  \leq C'(r+\epsilon)^n$ holds only if $r+\epsilon>1$, and that is where we need to use the fact that the sequence diverges! cheers!